# VIM: Not an editor command: MiniBufExplorer

Tags: vim, pathogen, minibufexplorer

I am using pathogen and I copied the minibufexplorer plugin:

```
wget -O ~/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim https://raw.github.com/fholgado/minibufexpl.vim/master/plugin/minibufexpl.vim
```

In vim when I try `:MiniBufExplorer` I get the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: MiniBufExplorer
```

OS: CentOS
Vim 7.3

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file should be put in the `.vim/bundle/plugin` directory, and not directly under `bundle`.

To fix it:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle/plugin
mv ~/.vim/bundle/minibufexpl.vim ~/.vim/bundle/plugin
```